# Product Review Do not submit

Tags: product, forms, review

The reviews are not submitting. In the frontend or the admin panel. 
I already dropped and recreated all the tables that are connected to the reviews - and that did not help!

I have the formkey in the proper place.
Everything that is supposed to be enabled, is and not, isn't.

I also have it set that guest are Allowed to post.

I believe the next step would be to compare and contrast the originals with the ones in my site - ANY OTHER BETTER SUGGESTIONS??

error.log:

```
Cannot send headers; headers already sent in , line 0
#0 /var/www/vhosts/dev.silverspeck.com/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php(115): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->canSendHeaders(true)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/dev.silverspeck.com/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(71): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->setHeader('HTTP/1.1', '404 Not Found')
#2 /var/www/vhosts/dev.silverspeck.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->noRouteAction()
#3 /var/www/vhosts/dev.silverspeck.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('noRoute')
#4 /var/www/vhosts/dev.silverspeck.com/app/code/community/ArtsOnIT/OfflineMaintenance/Controller/Router/Standard.php(46): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#5 /var/www/vhosts/dev.silverspeck.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): ArtsOnIT_OfflineMaintenance_Controller_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#6 /var/www/vhosts/dev.silverspeck.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#7 /var/www/vhosts/dev.silverspeck.com/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#8 /var/www/vhosts/dev.silverspeck.com/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#9 {main}
```

Comment: As Matthias has said, it sounds like you're getting an error causing the headers already sent.  In my case Apptha_AmazeReviews that was overriding the Mage_Review causing a silent issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, it would be great if you could have a look into the log files (system.log, exception.log) if there is anything in it, that points towards the problem.

Otherwise it will be hard to help you or have a better understanding of the problem.

A diff of the files of your system with a standard installation is always a good way to go.

Did you rewrite any logic, did you change core logic, did you install any extensions or themes?